# What does the phrase refer to after the comma?

Tags: grammar, comma-splices

The line below is taken from an article published in The New York Times.

> In 2012, Fran Lebowitz, the humorist and noted nemesis of Michael
>   Bloomberg, who was then New York City’s mayor, sneered that the
>   billionaire businessman and philanthropist could not stand the thought
>   of someone having a bigger job than his.

I can't understand weather the phrase `who was then New York City’s mayor` refers to Fran Lebowitz or Michael Bloomberg. Please help me figure this out.

Comment: How will it be if written as "In 2012, Fran Lebowitz, the humorist and noted nemesis of Michael Bloomberg, then New York City’s mayor, sneered....

Comment: @RamPillai Better, but still confusing. I'm still not clear from what it says which one was mayor.

Answer (score 1):

The parenthetical phrase, inside the commas, is supposed to point to the item immediately preceding it. This can go badly wrong if not done properly or too many players are involved. In this case the mayor was indeed Bloomberg and Fran really was his nemesis.